# How can I create my own helm chart package from the kube-prometheus-stack charts on github

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, kubernetes-helm

I'm trying to create my own helm chart package for prometheus and its components but I am trying to reuse parts of the kube-prometheus-stack helm chart on github : https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts/tree/main/charts/kube-prometheus-stack

I've modified the templates to my liking but when I try to create a package for them which I can then upload it to my repo I get the following :

```
helm package prometheus-chart/                                                                                                                 
Error: found in Chart.yaml, but missing in charts/ directory: alertmanager, kube-state-metrics, prometheus-node-exporter, prometheus-pushgateway
```

How can I get the templates from that repo, and create a deployable package from my local machine which I can then share it?

Answer (score 2):

These components **alertmanager, kube-state-metrics, prometheus-node-exporter, prometheus-pushgateway** are added as dependencies in the [Chart.yaml](https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts/blob/main/charts/kube-prometheus-stack/Chart.yaml). So the helm will check whether these dependencies are built or not.

So you need to build the dependencies as well by using this command

```
$ helm dependency build CHARTNAME
```

Example:

```
$ helm dependency build alertmanager
```

Once the dependencies are built you can update them using update command

```
$ helm dependency update CHARTNAME
```

For more detailed information refer to this official documents [doc1](https://helm.sh/docs/helm/helm_dependency_build/) [doc2](https://helm.sh/docs/helm/helm_dependency_update/)

Answer (score 1):

There are dependencies added in the `Chart.yml` file that are not downloaded, you need to run the command `helm dependency build <CHART>` in order to fetch them